# Не работает $.ajax внутри live()

Tags: jquery

Не силен в особенностях jQuery, поэтому интересует вопрос из заголовка топика. Пример кода:

```
$(selector).live(event, function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        success: function (html) {
            $(selector).html(html);
        }
    });
});

//не работает даже без ajax запроса

$(selector).live(event, function () {
    $(selector).html('some html');
});
```

Comment: Вполне рабочий пример. Чтобы баг отловить - нужен текст конкретного применения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо live в новых релизах jquery используется on.

Кстати обратите внимание на то что вверху это пример. Вы должны подставить туда нужный селектор и ивент. (Так на всякий случай обратил внимание.)

Comment: У меня на 1.8 on не работает. У него какие-то ключи надо проставлять, чтобы он как live работал?

Comment: а если в приведенном коде не подставден селектор и ивент - ето значит что я тупой?

Comment: on - работает как делегирование, $('body').on('click', 'selector', function(){});

Answer (score 1):

[Работает](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/yp4gC/)

- event - название event'а, e.g. `"click"`, `"mouseup"`
- selector - собственно селектор, e.g. `"div"`, `".content"`, `"#xxx"`

Comment: мде... бурная реакция на `selector` и `event` печаль...

Answer (score 0):

И что? Какой Jquery используете?

Потом - есть ли такой селектор? 
Событие наступает? Вызовите его сами.
Если Ajax даже с ошибкой не падает (Firebug смотрите), значит селектор/событие ошибка. Как вам написали, без реального примера сложно сказать.